# Don't want php script to execute the shell command as apache user when it is executed through browser?

Tags: php, apache, shell, unix, webserver

I have created a PHP script that generates some .gz files, when I execute the PHP script through command line (cli), it generate the .gz file having 'desert' as user but when the script is executed through browser it generates the .gz file with 'nobody' as user which should not happen. I want the generated file to have 'desert' user rather than 'nobody' user when the script is executed through browser.

Here is the code I have created:

```
$file='test';
$newFileGZipCommand = 'cat '.$file.'_new | gzip > '.$file.'.gz';
//$newFileGZipCommand = 'sudo -u desert cat '.$file.'_new | gzip > '.$file.'.gz'; // This does not work
$newFileGZipCommandExecute = shell_exec($newFileGZipCommand);
//chmod($file.'.gz',0777) or die("Unable to change file permission");
//chown($file.'.gz', 'directu') or die("Unable to change file Owner");
```

I tried doing changing the file permissions and owner through chmod() and chown() functions in php but it say "chown(): operation not permitted".

Any pointer to this is highly appreciated.

[Note: I cannot change the httpd.conf or any other configuration files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudo normally requires an interactive shell to enter your password. That's obviously not going to happen in a PHP script. If you're sure you know what you're doing and you've got your security issues covered, try allowing the Apache user to run `sudo` without a password, but only for certain commands.

For example, adding the following line in your sudoers file will allow Apache to run `sudo` without a password, only for the `gzip` command.

```
nobody ALL=NOPASSWD: gzip
```

Adjust the path and add any arguments to suit your needs.

**Caution:**

1. There might still be complications due to the way PHP calls shell
   commands.
2. Remember that it's very risky to allow the web server to
   run commands as root!

**Another alternative:**

Write a shell script with the suid bit to make it run as root no matter who calls it.

**Probably a better alternative:**

Write the commands to a queue and have cron pick them up, validate them (only allow known good requests), and run them, then mark that queue complete with the date and result.

Your end-user can then click/wait for update using ajax.

Hope it helps resolve your answer.

Comment: @MahavirMunot which option did you tried? i think last option will be better option. where you will be running the shell script which can do all the GZIPs for you

Comment: yes shell script also generated the files with user as nobody. still no progress

Comment: did you run shell script as `desert` user ?

Comment: :Yes, I tried it for temporary purpose but it still did not work.